# Will Google harm my ad's rating if my display URL in adwords does not exist?

Tags: advertising, google-ads, business

I have a service in a very big city, and to make my ads stand out, I display the name of the  neighborhood in the display URL, although the actual URL is always the same page with my services for any neighborhood. Will google decrease my rating for this? In a different note, you can also express your ideas about if it's sensible to do this or not, ie, the client might feel I'm deceiving them. Although this will be subjective, unless there is some scientific study.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can find details description about your question for below given official Google Sites.

Please Refer..

http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146676

Aslo Refer below sites this will help you a lot.>>http://www.ppchero.com/ultimate-guide-to-adwords-quality-score/

Please tell me your suggestion after getting your results.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: It doesn't say anything that helps me with my question, sorry.